# Tracking the entire history of RDP sessions

Tags: powershell, remote-desktop, rdp

We are trying to get the entire history of rdp servers via powershell.
I already looked at some example's like Qwinsta, quser, query user;
but that is not exactly what I am looking for.
I am looking for something I can write in Powershell to give me the entire history of it. from the day the machine is up.

example :

lets say I have a server I created last year.
I want to know who are the users that has logged into this server in the last year, which one is diss or active (kind of like query user or qwinsta) and when was the last time someone connected to this server.

```
NAME_OF_SERVER

 SESSIONNAME       USERNAME                 ID  STATE        DEVICE        LAST_LOGIN
 services                                    0  Disc                        
 console                                     1  Conn                        
 rdp-tcp#29        user1                     2  Active                      
                   user2                     3  Disc
```

appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Look in the server logs - there will be an event every time someone connects

Comment: is there anyway I can do it in powershell? I need it as a script
at the end I need to write the output into a database

Comment: Yes - you can query event logs using powershell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the history by querying for RDP event logs. There's a handful of different events that will denote an RDP logon, but I'm going to use the `RemoteConnectionManager` log here:

```
$RDPAuths = Get-WinEvent -LogName 'Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-RemoteConnectionManager/Operational' -FilterXPath @'
<QueryList><Query Id="0"><Select>
  *[System[EventID=1149]]
</Select></Query></QueryList>
'@ 

# Get specific properties from the event XML
[xml[]]$xml=$RDPAuths|Foreach{$_.ToXml()}
$EventData = Foreach ($event in $xml.Event) { 
  # Create custom object for event data
  New-Object PSObject -Property @{  
    TimeCreated = (Get-Date ($event.System.TimeCreated.SystemTime) -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss K')
    User   = $event.UserData.EventXML.Param1
    Domain = $event.UserData.EventXML.Param2
    Client = $event.UserData.EventXML.Param3
  }
}
$EventData | FT
```

You could pretty easily sort by user and find the last time they logged in using the output in `$EventData`:

```
TimeCreated                User   Domain   Client      
-----------                ----   ------   ------      
2021-09-23 12:02:03 -04:00 User01 MyDomain 10.10.10.10 
2021-09-23 12:00:42 -04:00 User01 MyDomain 10.10.10.10
2021-09-21 11:39:08 -04:00 User02 MyDomain 10.10.10.20
```

There's an obvious limitation here that you can only search as far back as your event log goes, so "from the day the machine is up." may not be possible depending on how your event logs are configured.

Another option here can be to just check `C:\users\*` for which users have ever logged in.

---

For checking *current* sessions, I mostly use `quser`. If your server is running Terminal Services, you can use the `RemoteDesktop` module and run commands like `Get-RDUserSession`.